# How to pass a map to a function in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I get a map of numbers from user and I want to pass the map to a function. I am able to display the map, but I can't find its length. I understand that in Python 3, maps have no length and they have to be converted in lists, but I had no success with that. I also noticed that if I attempt to display the length of the map before calling function info, then the info() will print an empty map.

```
def info(phys): 
  print("phys =",list(phys)) # it displays correctly only if I comment line 10
  print("len =",len(list(phys))) # it always displays 0 and I expect 3
  for i in phys:
    print(str(i))
  return

phys = map(int, input().strip().split()) # I pass "1 2 3"

print("len(phys) =",len(list(phys))) # if this command executes before next, line 2 will print "phys = []"
info(phys)
```

Comment: You exhausts iterator after first call of `list(phys)`. I'm sure there's a dupe somewhere.

Comment: The function `map` creates an generator object. If you want the kind of object that is called "map" in languages like C++ and Java, in Python those are called "dictionaries". You can create a dictionary with braces `{}` or with the function `dict`. If you want a list with the elements yielded by a generator, simply call the function `list` once on the generator and then use the resulting list from then on. Calling `list` on  the generator again won't work (more precisely, will result in an empty list) because it is exhausted.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a map() call is a generator which will yield resulting values only once. See relevant documentation about [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```
>>> phys = map(int, input().strip().split())
1 2 3 4
>>> list(phys)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(phys)
[] # Second attempt to iterate through "phys" does not return anything anymore
```

Apparently you want to materialize the values and work with them later. Then store them:

```
>>> phys = map(int, input().strip().split())
1 2 3 4
>>> result = list(phys)
>>> len(result)
4
>>> result[1]
2
>>> result[-2:]
[3, 4]
```